# What is the output of svcutil /l:CPP /out: output_Folder_Path wsdl_folder_path?

Tags: c++, wsdl, header-files, svcutil.exe

I was trying to create .cpp files from wsdl using svcutil. But unable to create cpp files.

svcutil /l:CPP /out: output_Folder_Path wsdl_folder_path

with this command it is creating .h header file. Please help me how to create .cpp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate code run `svcutil /t:metadata [yourfiles]`, which will create `wsdl/xsd` metadata only (into your current directory) and then run `wsutil .`.

[WsUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wsw/wsutil-compiler-tool) generates both source files and header files in C. Then, you might want to copy the code and generate a MSVC project in either C or C++.